# Real-time location plotting on map

Tags: angular, reactjs, analytics, real-time, twitter-streaming-api

I am working on a personal project where I want to analyse some data in real-time, my question is what can I use in order to display geo locations on map, in real-time?

I would like to have this done in React or Angular.

To be more clear:

1. I get some filtered tweets from twitter streaming API
2. I do some analysing stuff on each tweet
3. Here I want to plot geo locations on maps, the main features I would like to have are real-time visualisation, date range visualisation (for example if I select "last 24 hours" the map will display only locations for tweets which were processed in last 24 hours, beside these, it would be great if I could do some "time lapse" for a specific date range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of these for overlaying data onto maps:

1. [Google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)
2. [Leafletjs](https://leafletjs.com/)
3. [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/)